# Target container is not a DOM element in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, babeljs

I just started to learn **ReactJS** and I wrote my first code successfully. When the same pattern came to the component thing I am getting a error mentioning **_Invariant Violation: *registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.*** in the console. I am using react and babel cdn instead of downloading and importing.

```
<div id="=f_compo"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
    var compo= React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return (<h3>This is a simple component</h3>);
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(<compo/> ,document.getElementById('f_compo'));
</script>
```

This was my **index.html** code (I removed the cdn links in the head tag because of the error while posting the question) and *following thing* is the error that I am receiving.

**error:**

_invariant
_registerComponent
_renderNewRootComponent
wrapper
*renderSubtreeIntoContainer
render
wrapper

i
r
o
u
f*

Since there were few solutions in the google I need a clear explanation mentioning **Why this kind of error occur?** and **How it can be solved in formal manner?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo

```
// You declared id as "=f_compo"
<div id="=f_compo"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
    var compo= React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return (<h3>This is a simple component</h3>);
        }
    });
    //Find the same ID here. Right now it's "=f_compo" not "f_compo"
    ReactDOM.render(<compo/> ,document.getElementById('f_compo'));
</script>
```